# How to use regex capturing-group in custom sensitive information in DLP Office365

Tags: regex, security, passwords, office365, regex-group

I'm triyng to create a custom sensitive information type in Office365 (Security & Compliance Center) to match possible passwords (at least 8 digits, a letter, a number and a special character).

Regex (it works - e.g. https://regex101.com/)
**(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*["!@#$%¨&*()-_+])[A-Za-z\d"!@#$%¨&*()-_+]{8,}**

But when I try to set this code in Office365 I receive the error message below:

> *You cannot configure a pattern with groups or multiple match conditions like (.*,.+,.{0,n} or .{1,n}. Remove the group or the multiple match condition from the pattern to continue.*

Is there a way to circunvent this situation? Is it possible to reach the same result in another way?

Comment: Hi Faaceb, I've updated my answer and provided another way to achieve it, so please check if it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload your rule package XML file, the system validates the XML and checks for known bad patterns and obvious performance issues.

Here are some known issues that the validation checks for — a regular expression:

- Cannot have ".{0,m}" or ".{1,m}" in groups, and cannot have ".*" or ".+" in groups.
  For example, "(.{0,50000})" will not pass validation.
- Cannot begin or end with ".{1,m}"; instead, use just "."
  For example, ".{1,m}asdf" will not pass validation; instead, use just
  ".asdf".

We can try to use:

^ to match the beginning of a line position

(? ! [0-9]+$) not all Numbers are predicted for this position

(? ! [a-za-z]+$) predict that this position is not followed by all letters

[A-Za-z\d"!@#$%¨&()-_+] {8,} consists of at least 8 digits or these letters

$ matches the end of the line position

Please use the regex tool that you provided to test the following regex:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)(?![A-Za-z]+$)(?![!@!@#$%¨&()-_+]+$)[A-Za-z\d"!@#$%¨&()-_+]{8,}$
```

For more information, please review the following link:

[Potential validation issues to be aware of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/create-a-custom-sensitive-information-type#potential-validation-issues-to-be-aware-of)

Comment: This will match any 8+ character word and also includes a bunch of characters that you're likely not meaning to match due to the range `)-_`

Comment: Is there a way to circunvent this situation? Is it possible to reach the same result in another way?